# What theories are preserved under the product?

Tags: logic, model-theory, universal-algebra, direct-product

Although I haven't explicitly found this definition anywhere, it seems to me that the model-theoretic means of defining a product for $\mathcal{L}$-structures is as follows. Given a constant $c$ in the language $c^{\mathcal{M}\times\mathcal{N}}=(c^\mathcal{M},c^\mathcal{N})$; a function $f$, $f^{\mathcal{M}\times\mathcal{N}}((x_1,y_1),\dots,(x_n,y_n))=(f^\mathcal{M}(x_1,\dots,x_n),f^\mathcal{N}(y_1,\dots,y_n))$; and a relation $R$, $((x_1,y_1),\dots,(x_n,y_n))\in R^{\mathcal{M}\times\mathcal{N}}\iff (x_1,\dots,x_n)\in R^\mathcal{M}\land (y_1,\dots,y_n)\in R^\mathcal{N}$. (I based this off of observations from groups, rings, and preorders. Since this is only an observation, please correct me if I'm wrong.)

My question is what kinds of theories are perserved under this product? Specifically if $\mathcal{M},\mathcal{N}\models T$, is there a way of finding $S$ such that $\mathcal{M}\times\mathcal{N}\models S\subseteq T$? For instance, the theory of commutative rings is preserved, but the theory of division rings is not. I've tried to see if there is any pattern in the sentences specifically, but that failed to yield any results. I suspect that the answer is that it's not a property of specific sentences, but rather of the theories themselves. I suspect this because the sentence for the property of inverses in groups and that for the property of inverses in integral domains are almost exactly the same, structurally speaking, but only the former is preserved under products.

Edit: Confused division rings for integral domains originally.

Comment: In the algebraic setting (no relations; just operations), varieties (definable by equations) are closed under homomorphisms, subalgebras and direct products; quasi-varieties (definable by quasi-equations) are closed under  the formation of subalgebras, direct products and ultra products. I don't know if there is an alternative characterization, or a well-known example of a class precisely closed under direct products; but then again, so isn't the case of groups and rings which you use as an example.

Comment: The Los-Tarski theorem says a theory is closed under substructures iff it's a universal theory. Lyndon proved a theory is closed under homomorphic images iff it's a positive theory. These are called preservation theorems and I bet there is one for products.

Comment: The definition of the product of structures can be found e.g. in Hodges' model theory book(s), which I think also have a number of preservation results of the type you're looking for.

Comment: Keisler showed that the theories closed under the more general **reduced** direct products (reduced by a filter on the index set) are characterized as the Horn theories. But the classes of structures closed under ordinary direct products is more general (e.g. the class of atomic Boolean algebras) and harder to characterize.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to track down a copy of Weinstein's thesis (on microfilm, no less) and I can reproduce his characterization of direct product sentences here. It is fairly technical, and it is somewhat unsatisfying in that rather than being an inductively defined class of formulas (like the Horn sentences and strict Horn sentences), it is a class defined in terms of a recursive decision procedure.

There is an argument in Chang and Keisler that sentences preserved under finite direct products are preserved under arbitrary direct products, so really all we need to do is characterize the sentences that are preserved under finite direct products.

First some notation. Given formulas $\varphi_0$, $\varphi_1$, and $\varphi$, we write $\varphi_0 \times \varphi_1 \Rightarrow \varphi$ to mean that whenever $M \models \varphi_0(a_1,\dots,a_n)$ and $N \models \varphi_1(b_1,\dots,b_n)$, then $M \times N \models \varphi((a_1,b_1),\dots,(a_n,b_n))$. For any set of formulas $S$, we write

- $\neg S$ for the set of negations of elements of $S$,
- $\exists x S$ for the set of formulas of the form $\exists x \varphi$ for $\varphi \in S$ (for the *particular* variable $x$),
- $\forall x S$ for the set of formulas of the form $\forall x \varphi$ for $\varphi \in S$,
- $\bigvee S$ for the set of finite disjunctions of elements of $S$ (including the empty disjunction $\top$),
- $\bigwedge S$ for the set of finite conjunctions of elements of $S$ (including the empty conjunction $\bot$), and
- $\bigwedge^\ast S$ for the set of all maximal consistent conjunctions of elements of $S$.

In the case of $\bigvee S$ and $\bigwedge S$, assume that we have some fixed reasonable convention for listing these formulas to avoid redundancy. (For instance, we could require that the disjuncts/conjuncts are listed in some fixed lexicographic ordering with no repetitions.) In particular, when $S$ is finite, we want $\bigvee S$ and $\bigwedge S$ to be finite, and we want the maps $S \mapsto \bigvee S$ and $S \mapsto \bigwedge S$ to be computable.

Also, assume that we choose $\bigwedge^\ast S$ so that $\bigwedge^\ast S \subseteq \bigwedge S$. One thing to note is that there isn't a computable way to determine $\bigwedge^\ast S$ as a subset of $\bigwedge S$.

Let $(v_n)_{n< \omega}$ be an enumeration of our variables. Given a finite set of atomic formulas $S$, we define the following finite sets of atomic formulas:

- $S_0 = \bigvee \bigwedge (S \cup \neg S)$.
- $S_{n+1} = \bigvee \bigwedge \exists v_n S_n$, when $n$ is even.
- $S_{n+1} = \bigvee \bigwedge \forall v_n S_n$, when $n$ is odd.
- $S^\ast_0 = \bigvee \bigwedge^\ast (S \cup \neg S)$.
- $S^\ast_{n+1} = \bigvee \bigwedge^\ast \exists v_n S^\ast_n$, when $n$ is even.
- $S^\ast_{n+1} = \bigvee \bigwedge^\ast \forall v_n S^\ast_n$, when $n$ is odd.

Some things to note:

- The sequence $S_n$ is uniformly computable as a function of $S$, but the sequence $S^\ast_n$ will typically not be.
- We will always have $S^\ast_n \subseteq S_n$ for every $n<\omega$.
- Every formula is equivalent to a formula in $S^\ast_n$ for some $S$ and some $n$. A fortiori, this implies that every formula is equivalent to a formula in $S_n$ for some $S$ and some $n$.

Weinstein proved the following lemma:

> **Lemma.** Let $F$ be a finite autonomous set of formulas closed under $\wedge$ and $\vee$ up to equivalence. Let $u$ be any variable and let $\varphi_0$, $\varphi_1$, and $\varphi$ be formulas in $\bigvee\bigwedge\exists u F$. The following condition $(\ast)$ is sufficient to ensure that $\varphi_0 \times \varphi_1 \Rightarrow \varphi$.

> $(\ast)$ For every disjunct $\psi_0$ of $\varphi_0$ and every disjunct $\psi_1$ of $\varphi_1$, there is a disjunct $\psi$ of $\varphi$ such that for every conjunct $\exists u \chi$ of $\psi$, there are conjuncts $\exists u \chi_0$ of $\psi_0$ and $\exists u \chi_1$ of $\psi_1$ such that $\chi_0 \times \chi_1 \Rightarrow \chi$.

> Moreover, if $\varphi_0$ and $\varphi_1$ are elements of $\bigvee \bigwedge^\ast \exists u F$, then $(\ast)$ is necessary and sufficient for $\varphi_0 \times \varphi_1 \Rightarrow \varphi$ to hold.

> Finally, the above statements hold with all instances of $\exists$ replaced with $\forall$.

The definition of autonomous sets is given in Chang and Keisler. All that's relevant here is that our sets $S_n$ are all autononomous.

This lemma motivates the definition of the following primitive recursive predicate: $R(\varphi_0,\varphi_1,\varphi)$ holds if and only if $\varphi_0$, $\varphi_1$, and $\varphi$ belong to some common $S_n$ and

- if $n$ is $0$, then $\varphi_0 \times \varphi_1 \Rightarrow \varphi$;
- if $n$ is odd, then $(\ast\ast)$ for every disjunct $\psi_0$ of $\varphi_0$ and every disjunct $\psi_1$ of $\varphi_1$, there is a disjunct $\psi$ of $\varphi$ such that for every conjunct $\exists v_{n-1} \chi$ of $\psi$ there are conjuncts $\exists v_{n-1} \chi_0$ of $\psi_0$ and $\exists v_{n-1} \chi_1$ of $\psi_1$ such that $R(\chi_0,\chi_1,\chi)$ holds;
- if $n$ is even and positive, then $(\ast\ast)$ holds with $\forall$ instead of $\exists$.

This is a computable predicate because we can take $S$ to be the set of atomic formulas occurring in our formulas and we only need to check $n$ that is roughly as large as the quantifier ranks of our formulas.

The lemma enails that $R(x,y,z)$ satisfies the following:

- For any $\varphi_0$, $\varphi_1$, and $\varphi$ in some $S_n$, if $R(\varphi_0,\varphi_1,\varphi)$ holds, then $\varphi_0 \times \varphi_1 \Rightarrow \varphi$.
- For any $\psi_0$, $\psi_1$, and $\psi$ in some $S^\ast_n$, if $\psi_0 \times \psi_1 \Rightarrow \psi$, then $R(\psi_0,\psi_1,\psi)$ holds.

In particular, this means that a sentence $\chi$ is preserved under binary direct products (and therefore finite direct products and also arbitrary direct products) if and only if it is logically equivalent to a sentence $\varphi$ in some $S_n$ such that $R(\varphi,\varphi,\varphi)$ holds.

Comment: It might be possible to formalize the way in which the characterization of reduced product sentences is more satisfying than this characterization. I *think* that Horn sentences are a regular language. I wonder if direct product sentences can be similarly characterized. I would guess that the set of sentences given here is not a regular language, although I am not sure.

Comment: Would you have a reference for Horn clauses being a regular language?

Comment: @user1868607 I do not, and on reflection the requirement that the expressions in question be *sentences* rather than *formulas* might make it so that they're actually not a regular language. I still think that Horn formulas might be regular, but I don't have a reference for that either.

Answer (score 13):

The definition of product you suggest is indeed the standard one. It can be naturally extended to define the product $\prod_{i\in I} M_i$ of any family of structures $(M_i)_{i\in I}$. Here I'll include the case $I = \emptyset$. Then the product is the singleton structure $\{*\}$ with $f(*,\dots,*) = *$ for any function symbol $f$ and $R(*,\dots,*)$ for any relation symbol $R$. Below, when I talk about formulas being preserved under products, I mean under products of arbitrary families of structures (including the empty family - but I'll comment more on that below).

A simple (but non-optimal, see below) answer to your question is that *strict Horn formulas* are preserved under products.

A *strict basic Horn formula* has the form $\left(\bigwedge_{i=1}^n \varphi_i(x)\right)\rightarrow \psi(x)$, where each of the $\varphi_i(x)$ and $\psi(x)$ are atomic formulas. We allow the case $n = 0$, so any atomic formula is a basic Horn formula. A *strict Horn formula* is built from from basic Horn formulas by $\land$, $\forall$, and $\exists$ (but no $\lor$ or $\lnot$).

You can check that the strict basic Horn formulas are preserved under products, and then prove by induction that all strict Horn formulas are preserved under products. From this it follows that if $T$ is any theory and $S$ is the set of all strict Horn sentences which are entailed by $T$, then any product of models of $T$ is a model of $S$.

What's the word "strict" doing there? Well, we can define *basic Horn formula* and *Horn formula* exactly the same way, except we also allow $\psi(x)$ to be the contradictory formula $\bot$. A more common (and equivalent) definition is that a basic Horn formula is one of the form $\bigvee_{i=1}^n \varphi_i(x)$, where *at most one* of the $\varphi_i$ is an atomic formula, and the rest are negated atomic formulas. The point is that strict Horn formulas are preserved under arbitrary products, while Horn formulas are only preserved under products of *non-empty* families of structures.

Note that the axiom of integral domains $\forall x\forall y\,(xy = 0\rightarrow (x = 0\lor y = 0))$ is not a (strict) Horn sentence, and the fact that this axiom is not preserved under products proves that it is not equivalent to a (strict) Horn sentence. Similarly the sentence $\forall x\exists y\, (xy = 1)$ from the theory of groups is a (strict) Horn sentence, and it is preserved under products, but the sentence $\forall x \exists y\, (x\neq 0\rightarrow xy = 1)$ from the theory of fields is not a (strict) Horn sentence (since $x\neq 0$ is not atomic), and it is not preserved under products.

This is all very nice, but it raises the natural question: Is a first-order sentence preserved under products *if and only if* it is equivalent to a strict Horn sentence?

The answer is no - strict Horn sentences are preserved not just under products, but also under the more general construction of [reduced products](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduced_product). And as bof points out in the comments, Keisler proved that a first-order sentence is equivalent to a strict Horn sentence if and only if it is preserved under reduced products. This is Theorem 6.2.5 in *Model Theory* by Chang and Keisler (which I'll refer to as C&K below). What's actually proven there is that a sentence is equivalent to a Horn sentence if and only if it is preserved under reduced products by *proper* filters. Taking a reduced product by the improper filter gives a singleton structure, just like the empty product. See C&K Exercise 6.2.8 for the version about strict Horn sentences and arbitrary reduced products.

Some history: Keisler's original proof of Theorem 6.2.5 (from 1965) assumed the continuum hypothesis (CH). This is the proof in Section 6.2 of C&K. The same year, Galvin eliminated the dependence on CH, and Section 6.3 of C&K is largely devoted to an exposition of Galvin's proof. In 1971, Shelah famously proved what is now known as the [Keisler-Shelah isomorphism theorem](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF02771574), removing the dependency on CH from the earlier result of Keisler's that two structures are elementarily equivalent if and only if they have isomorphic ultrapowers. In this paper, Shelah asserted that the same technique could be used to give a cleaner proof of Theorem 6.2.5 without CH. Exercise 6.2.4 in C&K asks the reader to work out the details - and the exercise was solved in the form of a published paper by George C. Nelson in 1998 ([Preservation Theorems Without Continuum Hypothesis](https://doi.org/10.1023/A:1005028511181)).

To complete the story, here's some additional information from Chang and Keisler:

- There is an example (Example 6.2.3 in C&K) of a sentence which is preserved under (non-empty) products but which is not preserved under arbitrary reduced products by proper filters (and thus is not equivalent to a Horn sentence). The example given is the conjunction of the finitely many axioms for Boolean algebras, together with the sentence asserting that there exists an atom.  This example can be easily modified to one which is preserved under all products but is not equivalent to a strict Horn sentence by replacing "there exists an atom" with "$0=1$ or there exists an atom".
- Apparently, there is a true characterization of those first-order sentences preserved under products. C&K write "A syntactical characterization of direct product sentences was given by Weinstein (1965). Since his characterization is very complicated, we shall not give it here." It must indeed be very complicated, because C&K don't shy away from including extremely technical material elsewhere in their book! The reference is to Weinstein's PhD thesis "First-order properties preserved by direct product." It seems difficult to track down this thesis online. Maybe it's in the University of Wisconsin library? If someone reading this has a copy or knows the characterization, I would like to know what it is!
- Finally, C&K show (Propositions 6.2.8 and 6.2.9) that if a universal (respectively, existential)  sentence is preserved under (non-empty) products, then it is equivalent to a universal (respectively, existential) Horn sentence. And they give a reference, again to Weinstein's thesis, for the same result for $\forall\exists$-sentences. This is the best possible result, since the counterexample about atoms in Boolean algebras is an $\exists\forall$-sentence.

Comment: By the way, an example of a sentence preserved by direct products but not reduced products doesn't require the whole axiomatization of Boolean algebras. I think this does the trick: $$\forall y[0\le y]\land\exists x\forall y[y\le x\to(x\le y\lor y\le0)]$$

Comment: I don't know what Nelson did in 1998 but I think Chang & Keisler already removed the CH from Keisler's reduced product theorem in their *Model Theory* book (1960s), and Shelah gave a better proof but maybe too late to be in the C&K book.

Comment: @bof Thanks for the simpler example and for correcting my history! In your example sentence, I think you also need to include the condition $x\neq 0$. On the history: The first edition of C&K didn't come out till 1973. Somehow I managed to miss that the next Section (6.3) of C&K explains how to remove the dependency on CH. The introduction to Nelson's 1998 paper explains where it fits into the story - I'll edit later to clarify.

Comment: The Boolean algebra example you gave (Example 6.2.3 from C&K) is not entirely clear to me: why is it that no reduced product of Boolean algebras (with respect to the Fréchet filter) can have an atom?

Comment: @PoorPanda *Hint:* Show that the reduced product of countably many copies of the two-element Boolean algebra modulo the Fréchet filter is isomorphic to the quotient of $\mathscr{P}(\mathbb{N})$ by the ideal of finite sets. And show that this Boolean algebra is atomless. If the hint doesn't help, I recommend asking a new question.

Answer (score 3):

A (first-order) formula is *preserved by direct factors* if, whenever it holds in a direct product $A\times B$, it also holds in the factors $A$ and $B$. Keisler gave some kind of complicated syntactical characterization of formulas preserved by direct factors: Keisler, H. J., Properties preserved under direct factors. Notices of the American Mathematical Society, vol. 10 (1963), p. 302. Abstract 63T–169.

Now consider formulas of the form
$$Q[(\varphi_1\to\alpha_1)\land(\varphi_2\to\alpha_2)\land\cdots\land(\varphi_n\to\alpha_n)]\tag1$$
where each $\alpha_i$ is an atomic formula, each $\varphi_i$ is a formula preserved by direct factors, and $Q$ is a quantifier prefix. Formulas of the form $(1)$ are more general than Horn formulas and are still preserved by direct products. I believe it has been conjectured by someone (Weinstein? Keisler?) that every formula which is preserved by direct products is equaivalent to a formula of the form $(1)$. If true this would, when combined with Keisler's characterization of formulas preserved by factors, give a syntactical characterization of sentences preserved by products.

Comment: Weinstein asks in his thesis (Problem 1.1.3) whether the direct product formulas are the smallest class $J$ of formulas containing all plain or negated atomic formulas; closed under $\wedge$, $\forall$, and $\exists$; and containing $\varphi \to \psi$ whenever $\varphi$ is a factor formula and $\psi \in J$. He doesn't quite state it as a conjecture though. Maybe Keisler did at some point?

Comment: @JamesHanson Thanks, that must be what I had in mind. I never understood why people bother making a distinction between "questions" and "conjectures". I suppose the difference is that a "conjecture" includes an opinion as to what the answer ought to be. So what, opinions are irrelevant in mathematics.

Comment: I think that mathematical questions are often stated in the form of "conjectures" not because the author wishes to opine as to what the answer should be, but because, in languages such as English, questions are grammatically more complicated than declarative sentences, which in mathematics may already be rather complicated. I think that in mathematics a "conjecture" should mean, not "a proposition believed to be true though there is as yet no proof" but simply "an interesting proposition which has not been proved or refuted".